# ArduinoHTTPClient websocket undocumented max message size?

Tags: websocket, arduino

I have an Arduino MKRNB 1500 (with LTE-M network capability).
My code uses a websocket to upload messages to a server. The messages are uploaded every second or so of around 800-1000 bytes. My websocket server accepts these messages (i have tried with a browser client). But the ArduinoHTTPClient library WebSocketClient refuses to send messages that are over 128 bytes. The Arduino just hangs from that point onwards.
Because of the network latency, this means i cannot send more than around 600 bytes a second.
This limitation seems arbitrary, and is not documented as far as i have seen. It can be easily reproduced using the following code. Sending smaller messages more frequently is not an option because the network latency of LTE-M is around 150ms.

How can i send larger messages?

```
#include <ArduinoHttpClient.h>
#include <MKRNB.h> //For LTE-M or NB-IOT connections
#include "arduino_secrets.h"

// initialize the LTE-M library instance
NBClient nbClient;
GPRS gprs;
NB nbAccess;
char server[] = "echo.websocket.org";  // server address
const char PINNUMBER[] = "0000";  //  = SIM SECRET_PINNUMBER;
int port = 80; // port 80 is the default for HTTP
WebSocketClient client = WebSocketClient(nbClient, server, port);

int count = 120;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // LTE-M connection
  Serial.println(F("Connecting to LTE-M network"));
  boolean connected = false;
  while (!connected) {
    if ((nbAccess.begin(PINNUMBER) == NB_READY) &&
        (gprs.attachGPRS() == GPRS_READY)) {
      connected = true;
    } else {
      Serial.println("Not connected");
      delay(1000);
    }
  }
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("starting WebSocket client");
  client.begin();

  while (client.connected() and count <= 1000) {
    Serial.print("Sending hello ");
    Serial.println(count);

    // send a hello #
    client.beginMessage(TYPE_TEXT);
    client.print(count);
    client.print(": ");
    int i = 0;
    while (i<= count){
      client.print("X");
      i++;
    }
    client.endMessage();

    // increment count for next message
    count++;

    // check if a message is available to be received
    int messageSize = client.parseMessage();

    if (messageSize > 0) {
      Serial.println("Received a message:");
      Serial.println(client.readString());
    }
    delay(1000);
  }

  Serial.println("disconnected");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After examining the ArduinoHttpClient library, it turns out the WebSocketClient.h file has a limited buffer defined on line 89:

```
uint8_t iTxBuffer[128];
```

i changed that to

```
uint8_t iTxBuffer[4096];
```

And the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

custom size must be supported soon.

https://github.com/arduino-libraries/ArduinoHttpClient/issues/68